# How to sum up certain values from dataframe using loop on certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary and a DataFrame with two columns: `name` and `salary`. I want to sum the salary where the name matches the individual values of the dictionary.
This is what I have so far.
I want to sum the salary of managers, clerks, and analysts separately.

```
import pandas as pd

a = ['manager','sales','clerk','manager','analayst','sales','manager','analayst' ,'sales','clerk','clerk','analayst']
b = [45000,78000,12000,45000,96000,78000,56000,95000,84000,75000,95000,
   26000]
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':a,'salary':b})

sum = 0
k = 0
c = []

for i in a:
    if i not in c:
        c.append(i)

for j in range(len(df)):
    while k < len(c):
        p = c[k]
        print(p)
        
        d = df[df['name'] == p]['salary'].sum()
        k += 1[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easy separate the sum like  of managers, clerks, and analysts etc. using group by function . That is helpful to you easy solve you sum separated form

```
a=['manager','sales','clerk','manager','analayst','sales','manager','analayst' ,'sales','clerk','clerk','analayst']

b=[45000,78000,12000,45000,96000,78000,56000,95000,84000,75000,95000, 26000]

df=pd.DataFrame({'name':a,'salary':b})

df.groupby("name")["salary"].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

I m guessing you want an output like this -

```
>>> a=['manager','sales','clerk','manager','analayst','sales','manager','analayst' ,'sales','clerk','clerk','analayst']
>>> b=[45000,78000,12000,45000,96000,78000,56000,95000,84000,75000,95000,26000]
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'name':a,'salary':b})
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df.groupby('name').sum().reset_index()
       name  salary
0  analayst  217000
1     clerk  182000
2   manager  146000
3     sales  240000
>>>
```

If yes you can easily do this by a [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) , it enables you to group/cluster your data points and over each subset you can perform you desired aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Use:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html

below is the snippet of the result..

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = ['manager', 'sales', 'clerk', 'manager', 'analyst', 'sales', 'manager', 'analyst', 'sales', 'clerk',  'clerk', 'analyst']
>>> b = [45000, 78000, 12000, 45000, 96000, 78000, 56000, 95000, 84000, 75000, 95000, 26000]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': a, 'salary': b})
>>> df
       name  salary
0   manager   45000
1     sales   78000
2     clerk   12000
3   manager   45000
4   analyst   96000
5     sales   78000
6   manager   56000
7   analyst   95000
8     sales   84000
9     clerk   75000
10    clerk   95000
11  analyst   26000
>>> df.groupby(['name']).sum()
         salary
name
analyst  217000
clerk    182000
manager  146000
sales    240000
```